# Shimano 6 speed cassette

Tags: derailleur

I have a new bicycle, my first with multiple gears. The shifter is on the right handlebar. Does gear 0ne on the shifter indicate the smallest wheel on the cassette or the largest wheel on the cassette? If I am climbing a hill do I need the large wheel or the small wheel?

Comment: Basically 1 is always the easiest gear. It's not matter on which side the handle bar is.

Comment: Though some may be redundant. For example, middle front small back may be the same as big front big back or something if you have both multiple chainrings and gears in the back.

Comment: Why don't you try both settings? You will know this immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Gear 1 indicates the largest cog on the rear.  It will be the easiest to pedal and make you go the slowest for a given pedal speed.  You want lower gears for slow speed, whether from going uphill, being lazy, or whatever cause.  They allow you to maintain your desired pedaling cadence.